# EXCEL - VBA - copy paste between 3 sheets

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to copy/paste information between three different Sheets.
The first two I only want to compare information with a `If` and if the condition is met then from sheet n2 copy all rows to a third sheet. My problem is that the code only finds the first value and stops.  Here's the code.

```
Sub fallidas2()

Dim iLastRow As Long
    Dim I As Long
    Dim l As Long
    Dim erow As Long

    erow = Sheets("Failed_Trades").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    Workbooks("modelo titulos UK").Worksheets("xlsConsultaConciliacion").Select

    iLastRow = Worksheets("xlsConsultaConciliacion").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    iLastRow2 = Worksheets("Fallidas").Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 3 To iLastRow
      For l = 2 To iLastRow2
        If Sheets("xlsConsultaConciliacion").Cells(I, 1) = Sheets("Fallidas").Cells(l, 2) Then
          Worksheets("Fallidas").Rows(I).EntireRow.Copy _
                    Destination:=Sheets("Failed_Trades").Range("A" & erow)

        End If
      Next l
    Next I

End Sub
```

Comment: You never increment `erow` so you are pasting over the same cells again and again. Also, there are quicker ways to do this, using Find or Match which will avoid having to loop twice. Last, please read up on indenting your code.

Comment: Both of your For loops use `I` as counter? why?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns - one is a lower case L I think (still confusing though when there is a whole alphabet from which to choose).

Comment: @sjr Oh!!! Good eyes! You are right. I would suggest OP to use different letter because those are so similar.

Comment: thanks for your input guys!how can i increment erow?

Comment: Increment `erow` every time you copy. So after your: `Worksheets("Fallidas").Rows(I).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Failed_Trades").Range("A" & erow)`, in the next line add the following: `erow = erow + 1`. Also, just to help with the code: I would capture the 2 ranges (from `Worksheets("xlsConsultaConciliacion")` and `Worksheets("Fallidas")`) into arrays. It will help with performance

Answer (score 0):

You need to increment erow as part of the If statement.  I've also included an Exit For statement in there so that it doesn't keep searching through the 2nd worksheet after the first match is found.  But maybe you want it to find additional matches and populate the same information repetitively on the third sheet?

```
    If Sheets("xlsConsultaConciliacion").Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("Fallidas").Cells(l, 2) Then
        Worksheets("Fallidas").Rows(i).EntireRow.Copy Destination:=Sheets("Failed_Trades").Range("A" & erow) 
        erow = erow + 1
        Exit For
    End If
```